# Getting a forbidden on nginx when accessing /api

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I have a nuxt application with a BE laravel.   Below is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/solvo/app/dist;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name server_name;

         location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

    location /api{
      alias "/var/www/html/solvo/mint-api-solvo/public";
      try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
          location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/solvo/app/public/index.php;
    }
     }

       location @api {
            rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
       }


    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;

}
```

any idea as to why I am getting a 403 Forbidden when accessing the URL /api?

getting this error in logs

```
 directory index of "/var/www/html/solvo/app/public/" is forbidden, client: xx.xx.xx.x,
```

Comment: The error is caused because Nginx cannot find an `index.html` file in that directory. You could try adding `index.php` to the `index` line (as stated in your own configuration file). You could try removing `$uri/` from the `try_files` statement in the `location /api` block.